# How to read Linux environment variables in c++

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables

In my c++ program I want to load some environment variables from the shell into some strings. How can this be done?

Answer (score 45):

Use the getenv() function - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv. I like to wrap this as follows:

```
std::string GetEnv( const std::string & var ) {
     const char * val = std::getenv( var.c_str() );
     if ( val == nullptr ) { // invalid to assign nullptr to std::string
         return "";
     }
     else {
         return val;
     }
}
```

which avoids problems when the environment **variable does not exist**, and allows me to use C++ strings easily to query the environment. Of course, it does not allow me to test if an environment variable does not exist, but in general that is not a problem in my code.

Comment: Sometimes you may want to differentiate between 'unset' and 'empty'

Comment: Must.... make...... template..... predicated on.... CharT. Oh wait, that requires SFINAE. Oh well. +1

Comment: you might use `boost::optional<std::string>` as a return type to differentiate between absent and empty.

Comment: @Matthieu I would say 99% of the time I don't care if an env variable actually exists - I just want to know its value and am happy with an empty string if it doesn't. Rather than complicate things enormously by bringing boost into the picture, I would simply test for existence by calling getenv() directly. Or possibly write a EnvVarExists() function.

Comment: I was more thinking about the case where you might want a sensible default, but this can be achieved by providing an overload with a second parameter :)

Answer (score 9):

Same as in C: use getenv(variablename).

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use char* env[]

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;env[i]!=NULL;i++)
    printf("%s\n",env[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121214035640/http://hanoo.org/index.php?article=get-environment-variables-c-linux) is a complete article about your problem, from *my website*.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: It's "function", not "fonction". (Referring to your website.) Also, the third parameter to `main()` is non-standard, and not guaranteed to work on all platforms / compilers.

Comment: does this work with environment variables that are exported/set after the program starts ?

Comment: nurettin: I think so but try to be sure ;)