# How to put the contents of getenv() into a string

Tags: c++, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read Linux environment variables in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866134/how-to-read-linux-environment-variables-in-c)

How can the following be changed to do what it's supposed to do?

```
string s = getenv("PATH");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866134/how-to-read-linux-environment-variables-in-c/5866166#5866166

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to check that the `getenv` succeeded first:

```
char const* tmp = getenv( "PATH" );
if ( tmp == NULL ) {
    //  Big problem...
} else {
    std::string s( tmp );
    //  ...
}
```

(Supposing I've guessed correctly with regards to "what it's
supposed to do".)

Comment: +1 You can make your answer better by elaborating more on the "Big Problem" of Undefined behavior when passing null char* pointers to String constructor. OP should be made aware of that important detail.

Comment: @Als Good point.  In this case, I would expect a careful programmer to want to do something different if `getenv` returns a null pointer (fails), but it's definitely worth pointing out that creating a string with a null pointer is undefined behavior (and **not** an empty string, unless that happens to accidentally be the "undefined" behavior).

Answer (score 15):

```
std::string getEnvVar(std::string const& key)
{
    char const* val = getenv(key.c_str()); 
    return val == NULL ? std::string() : std::string(val);
}
```